# Im using datatable in my project mvc , i want display Categorie name in place of categorye id foreign key in table courses

Tags: datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{``

```
        ApplicationDbContext db =   new ApplicationDbContext();
        var course = db.Courses

            .Include(d=>d.Competences)

            .Include(d=>d.Sequences)
            .ToList().Select(p => new { Id = p.Id, Titre = p.Titre, ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription, Price = p.Price, CategorieId = p.CategorieId });
```

var query = from q in db.Courses
join cat in db.Categories.AsEnumerable()

```
on q.CategorieId equals cat.Libelle
enter code here
                 return Json(new { data = course },
```

JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

```
    }
```